# Multiple map inside map javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have an array of objects that has children. Those children also has children. I want to print those out in order in React. So what I am trying to do is multiple maps inside eachother.

I can manage to do one map inside another like this:

```
 org = workplaces.map((item) =>
    <ul className="" style={{ background: "grey" }}>
    <li>{item.workplace}</li>
    {item.children.map((item2) => {
     return <li>{item2.workplace}</li>
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

but when I try to do another map inside item2, I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" for item2 (it does have children):

```
org = workplaces.map((item) =>
    <ul className="" style={{ background: "grey" }}>
    <li>{item.workplace}</li>
    {item.children.map((item2) => {
      item2.children.map((item3) => {
        return <li>{item3.workplace}</li>
      })
      return <li>{item2.workplace}</li>
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

Is it possible to make 3 maps inside eachother?

Comment: yes, but it looks like at least one of your nested objects doesn't have children. Also, nested `li` elements should be within their own `ul`.

Comment: _"Is it possible to make 3 maps inside eachother?"_... yes. The error indicates that you're assuming something is an array when it is actually `undefined`. Without seeing where your data comes from and how it's assigned to state, this cannot be answered

Comment: @pilchard looks like a flat list to me which is ok

Comment: Your `return` statements are kind of a mess. You're not doing anything with the result of `item2.children.map()`. You'll probably want to return a fragment, eg `return <>{item2.children.map(...)}<li>{item2.workplace}</li></>`

Comment: @phil ah yes, I just assumed due to the nested properties the OP wanted a nested list, but you're right, it could just be flat.